# How to create an RSS feed of my site that can be shared and customized by others

Tags: rss

I'd like to create widget that offers visitors of my site the option to copy embed code for my rss feed to share on to their site.  Also, to offer an option to customize.  I'm specifically looking to do exactly what this site does...

http://prospectheights.patch.com/widgets/articles/quicklist

I'm not strong programmer and hoping to find an out of the box solution, but if anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd be grateful!  Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use CSS styling, perhaps with some dynamic JavaScript formatting the layout & inserting that styling.
http://duckduckgo.com/?q=format+RSS+CSS+JavaScript

jQuery is handy here:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-build-an-rss-reader-with-jquery-mobile-2/

http://www.egrappler.com/rss-driven-dynamic-jquery-news-slider-plugin-dynamic-news/

http://www.jquerynewsticker.com/

http://willcode4beer.com/ware.jsp?set=jquery_rss